# function not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that is supposed to remove a image when dragged to a div, but it is not working on firefox and I don't know why. and I have the following error message on the console "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement]"

```
$(function() {
   $('#img_garbage').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui);
        $(ui.draggable).remove();

        if (event.srcElement == undefined){
        var dragged = event.target;
        }
        else {

        dragged = event.srcElement.alt}
        console.log(dragged);
        deleteCookie(dragged);

        $("#"+dragged).remove();

    }
   });
});
```

Comment: What messages do you get in the Firebug console?

Comment: What *is* it doing?  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  Do the selectors find the element(s) you expect?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you step through it in the debugger, where does it go wrong?  What is the HTML associated with it?

Comment: Try `event.target` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target

Comment: the message it is giving on the console is the following:

Comment: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement]

Answer (score 3):

You want the id of the element, so should be:

```
var dragged = event.target.id;
```

Comment: well that will delete remove the div with an id img_garbage not the image I am trying to delete

Comment: Well, you are dragging that div. If the image is indide that div, just do `$("#"+dragged).find('img').remove();`